# Triangle inequality for signed measures $| \mu +\nu |(A) \leq |\mu|(A) +|\nu|(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

I want to show that for finite signed measures $\mu, \nu$ defined on $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ the following triangle inequality holds

$
| \mu +\nu |(A) \leq |\mu|(A) +|\nu|(A)
$

for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$. If $E, F$ form a Hahn decomposition where $E$ is negative and $F$ is positive, then by definition $\mu^+(A) = \mu(A \cap F)$ and $\mu^-(A) = -\mu(A \cap E)$. Further by definition $|\mu|(A) = \mu^+(A) + \mu^-(A)$ and it can be shown that $\mu = \mu^+-\mu^-$ where at least one if the measures $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ is finite.

Hence

$
| \mu +\nu |(A) =  (\mu +\nu)^+(A) + (\mu +\nu)^-(A)
$

and

$
(\mu +\nu)^+(A) = (\mu^++v^+-\mu^--v^-)(A\cap F) = \mu(A\cap F) + v(A\cap F) + \mu(A\cap F \cap E) + v(A\cap F \cap E) = \mu(A\cap F) + v(A\cap F) + \mu(A\cap \emptyset) + v(A\cap \emptyset) = \mu(A\cap F) + v(A\cap F).
$

Similar holds for $(\mu +\nu)^-(A)$. I don't understand how we would ever get a strict inequality not just an equality. How to show this? This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500723/triangle-inequality-for-signed-measure) does not seem to adress why there's not only an equality.

Comment: Try this with $\nu=-\mu$. I guess that should help.

Comment: $(\mu^++v^+-\mu^--v^-)(A\cap F) \ne\mu(A\cap F) + v(A\cap F) + \mu(A\cap F \cap E) + v(A\cap F \cap E).$

Comment: @Anne Bauval could you please state what it should be then? Unfortunately I cannot see why its not an equality.

Comment: The supports need not be the same for the positive part of the sum and the individual measures.

Comment: Indeed, and look at Severin's first comment.